# Ложная ошибка «Сообщение дублирует ...» при задании вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Хочу задать следующий вопрос:

```
Как правильно, «электролизер» или «электролизёр»?
```

Но система не даёт мне этого сделать со следующей ошибкой:

> Сообщение дублирует [Мародер или мародёр](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434914/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%80)

[image]

Вопрос, который я хочу задать, и который система предлагает в качестве дублирующего, хоть и различаются в двух словах, но всё же не являются дубликатами.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше сообщение. Мы проверим указанную информацию и дадим ответ позже.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, причиной данного поведения является алгоритмы движка. Ваше сообщение и сообщение, на которое ссылается движок, скорее всего, для движка выглядят очень похожими, как результат он не дает их задать. Предположу, что подобная проверка нужна для предотвращения публикации однотипных обширных вопросов вида «Что такое X/Y/Z» и т.д.

Для публикации вашего вопроса, пожалуйста, попробуйте уточнить его, добавив контекст или примеры употребления слов.